# Test -lt Command in the If Statement with a String Variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I was looking into the If statements in bash, and uncovered some unexpected behaviour.

Let's say that I have a variable `b=2`. It is obviously a string. If I do an if statement like this:

```
if [ $((b)) -lt 5 ]
then
...
fi
```

It successfully passes the conditional statement , as indeed 2 is less than 5.
However, if I remove the double brackets (`if [ b -lt 5 ]`), it still works the same way as the example before. Can you please tell me why it is so? I thought that `-lt` works only with integers, not with strings. Does it implicitly convert the string variable to the integer type here?

Comment: I get `bash: [0: command not found` and `bash: [b: command not found`. I have no idea why it doesn't give this error to you. Don't you not have spaces inside `[` and `]`, or use `[[` `]]` instead?

Comment: @egmont Yes, sorry, I do have spaces there. I will correct my question now

Comment: Adding the spaces but leaving single-brackets, I get "`-bash: [: b: integer expression expected`". Please report the *exact* syntax you're using.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Here is the exact syntax :  `b=3;if [ $b -lt 5 ]; then echo "Wow,it works!"; fi` . `b` is definitely not an integer, because  I have just created a new variable `c` with the same syntax and it still worked.

Comment: Variables in bash are essentially untyped (although you can use `declare -i` to enforce a kind of basic type checking). Note that `[ b -lt 5 ]` (as you wrote in the question) is **not** the same as `[ $b -lt 5 ]` as you wrote in your comment. However `(( b < 5 ))` and `(( $b < 5 ))` **are** equivalent (at least if `b` is defined).

Comment: @steeldriver You are right , of course. However, then shouldn't the statement `$b -lt 5` produce an error as b is not of a type integer but is actually untyped? It looks like bash *automatically* converts it to integer to evaluate the expression. Is it true? (it has been my main question)

Comment: ... well try it with a non-numeric value like `b=foobar; if [ $b -lt 5 ]; then echo less; fi`

Comment: @Alex.Kh If that's the question, then the answer is yes: in contexts where the shell needs integer values for some operation, it parses whatever string it has (it's *always* a string) into integer form. In your example, `[ $b -lt 5 ]` expands to `[ 3 -lt 5 ]`, and the "[", "3", "-lt", "5", and "]" are *all* just strings. The "[" gets treated as a command name, and the others are passed to it as (string) arguments. The `[` command then figures out that `-lt` is an integer operator, so it parses `3` and `5` as integers to compare them.

Comment: @steeldriver . Thank you, that answered my question perfectly.

Comment: @Alex.Kh I have attempted a fuller answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash variables are essentially untyped<sup>1</sup> - tests that only make sense for a particular type may fail at evaluation time if the value cannot be converted successfully. Valid forms of arithmetic test are:

```
$ b=4; if [ $b -lt 5 ]; then echo "less"; fi
less
```

or (using arithmetic expression syntax)

```
$ b=4; if (( $b < 5 )); then echo "less"; fi
less
```

As noted in the `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` section of`man bash`, the dereferencing `$` may be omitted in the `(( ... ))` context:

> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter  expansion  is 
>   performed before the expression is evaluated.  **Within an
>   expression, shell    variables may also be referenced by name without 
>   using  the  parameter    expansion  syntax**.

So

```
$ b=4; if (( b < 5 )); then echo "less"; fi
less
```

The same is **not** true in the POSIX `[   ]` test syntax, which will treat `b` as a string literal:

```
$ b=4; if [ b -lt 5 ]; then echo "less"; fi
-bash: [: b: integer expression expected
```

If you try to perform a `[  ]` arithmetic test on a variable that contains a non-numeric *value* it will fail for the same reason i.e. that the value cannot be converted to a numeric type:

```
$ b=foo; if [ $b -lt 5 ]; then echo "less"; fi
-bash: [: foo: integer expression expected
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Rudimentary type checking may be implemented using `declare -i` if the `-u` shell option is set ex.

```
$ set -u
$ declare -i b
$ b=foo
bash: foo: unbound variable
$ echo $?
1
```

whereas assignment of a valid numeric value

```
$ b=4
$ echo $?
0
```

succeeds.

Comment: Thank you again for such an extensive answer!